# Google Postmaster API - how to pass startDate parameter?

Tags: php, google-apps-script, google-api, google-postmaster

Here is my code to get the traffic stats from my Google Postmaster account. It works perfectly without the date parameters, but as soon as I add a startDate it doesn't work anymore

```
$url = 'https://gmailpostmastertools.googleapis.com/v1/domains/'.$this_domain.'/trafficStats/?pageSize=9999&startDate=20221001&endDate=20221030';

$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array(
  'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
  'Accept: application/json'
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

$google_postmaster_api_json = curl_exec($ch);


$google_postmaster_api = json_decode($google_postmaster_api_json, true);
echo "<pre>";
var_dump($google_postmaster_api);
echo "</pre>";
```

if the StartDate parameter is added, the API returns this error:

```
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "startDate": Cannot bind query parameter. 'startDate' is a message type. Parameters can only be bound to primitive types.
Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "endDate": Cannot bind query parameter. 'endDate' is a message type. Parameters can only be bound to primitive types.
```

If I try to POST it as a json instead, the result returned is NULL even if there should be data returned

```
      $json_request = '{
        "dateRanges": [{ "startDate": "2022-10-01", "endDate": "2022-10-15" }],
      }';

      $ch = curl_init();
      $headers = array(
        'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token,
        'Accept: application/json'
      );
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json_request);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST');
      curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");
      curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);

      $google_postmaster_api_json = curl_exec($ch);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/postmaster/reference/rest/v1/domains.trafficStats/list) (although I have to say it's not 100% clear) the "startDate" and "endDate" parameters are actually composites, and to generate a valid request you must specify each component of those dates (year, month and day) as separate parameters in your URL, in this format:

```
startDate.day=X&startDate.month=X&startDate.year=X&endDate.day=X&endDate.month=X&endDate.year=X
```

(where `X` is of course replaced by a valid numeric value for each parameter).

The documentation entries for "startDate" and "endDate" show the type as "Object (Date)", where the "Date" is a link to the [Date section of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/postmaster/reference/rest/v1/domains.trafficStats/list#Date) where it describes the individual fields which make up a date for the purposes of the API requests.

I was able to confirm this by using the "Try this method" part of the documentation to generate a request to the API, and the Network tool in my browser showed the URL it generated as a result of submitting the request from the form, and the date portions of the URL querystring matched the format I've shown above.

---

P.S. It definitely does not support sending the data in JSON format via a POST request though. The documentation is clear that it must be a GET request and that the request body must be empty.

Comment: Thank you so much! Google doesn't like keeping things simple apparently, and their documentation was confusing and lacked examples